# What does it mean when the "Grouping Interval Exceeds 0.1 standard Deviation Units"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size

I found this quote by Royston, but I'm unsure what I'm supposed to calculate to determine if I satisfy the condition.

"The Shapiro-Wilk test for non-normality is highly sensitive to the presence of ties due to grouping or rounding of the raw data, and should not be used if the grouping interval exceeds 0.1 standard deviation units."

I have a small sample size of 12 points with ties.

Ref: [1]: Royston, J.P. (1989),
"Correcting the Shapiro-Wilk W for ties,"
Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation, Volume 31, Issue 4

1 set of Points (I have 1000 sets)

```
Error
0
-1
-1
-1
9
0
10
-4
-1
-3
2
-2
```

Comment: Precise reference? Friend of mine, although he is not active here and speaks for himself. However,  I doubt he or anyone else can promise much with 12 data points. But give us the 12 points and their consistency with normality can be discussed.

Comment: Suppose values are binned with lower limits that are multiples of 10, but the standard deviation is 50. Then grouping interval (bin width) is 0.2 SD and that is too coarse on this advice. Bin width of 1, then 0.02 SD and you should be OK. Bin width here can mean resolution of the data, so even if you are not deliberately binning, the data come already binned, e.g. if you have people's heights in cm, weights in kg then 1 cm or 1 kg might be the bin width.

Comment: Ref:  [1]: Royston, J.P. (1989),
"Correcting the Shapiro-Wilk W for ties,"
Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation, Volume 31, Issue 4

Comment: Does anyone know if Royston's SW extended method has been implemented in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing first on the original question:

Suppose values are binned with lower limits that are multiples of 10, but the standard deviation is 50. Then the grouping interval (bin width) is 0.2 SD and -- on this advice -- that is too coarse.

If you had a bin width of 1, and the same SD, then the bin width is 0.02 SD and you should be OK.

Bin width here can mean resolution of the data. Even if you are not deliberately binning, data reported to some level of resolution (conventional rounding) come already binned. For example, if you have people's heights in cm, weights in kg then 1 cm or 1 kg might be the bin width

I add two further comments here:

C1. Throwing a bundle of tests at that small sample shows unsurprisingly that some tests are failed and some are not. Here is a clutch of tests with Stata output.

```
. mvtest normality error, all

Test for multivariate normality

    Mardia mSkewness =  1.811912     chi2(1) =    5.889   Prob>chi2 =  0.0152
    Mardia mKurtosis =  3.489294     chi2(1) =    0.120   Prob>chi2 =  0.7294
    Henze-Zirkler    =  .9252062     chi2(1) =    6.899   Prob>chi2 =  0.0086
    Doornik-Hansen                   chi2(2) =    9.308   Prob>chi2 =  0.0095

. swilk error

                   Shapiro-Wilk W test for normal data

    Variable |        Obs       W           V         z       Prob>z
-------------+------------------------------------------------------
       error |         12    0.79420      3.439     2.406    0.00805
```

This kind of shotgun approach would be appalling style because of the temptation to pick the result you prefer, but here is used to illustrate the nature of the problem, not to provide a solution.

C2. If you have essentially 1000 replicates with 12 or so values in each, I would be pretty happy to see, as a matter of "borrowing strength", a collective test for the pooled distribution. You need that any way to pick up indications of an alternative to the normal, should one make sense.

Comment: Why do I get a -1?

Comment: You're asking, I think, why you got a downvote. The downvoter (a) wasn't me (b) left no comment to explain, so my ignorance on the point is absolute. (If you're assuming or implying that it was me, that is quite unwarranted. I happen to be the only identifiable person reacting to your question, but many, many people here have downvote privileges.)

Comment: Nick, I certainly appreciate your assistance and I wasn't implying it was you (I gave you the tick and an upvote).  I was just hoping that whoever gave it to me would explain why.  The assignment of scores and badges really puzzles me as they seem to come randomly and without due cause.

Comment: Fair enough. Your question is certainly worth an upvote from me, so you end up ahead. FWIW, I think there are occasionally good reasons for downvoting and not declaring oneself, but the case for explaining what's wrong should usually be stronger.